# 削除された投稿を読めるユーザがいる事を、削除操作時に明示して欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求

[権限・モデレーターツールへのアクセス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) に「削除済み投稿の表示」という物があります。
多くのユーザはこの存在を、この権限を取得して初めて知るのではないでしょうか。
現状、回答を削除する際に聞かれるのは、

> このポストを削除しますか?

という確認だけのようで、質問の削除の際もこの点は触れられていないようです。
これでは不十分だと思います。

削除しても一部のユーザからは読める状態のままである事が伝わるメッセージにしていただきたいです。

---

参考: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: 「※投稿のURLを知っている一部ユーザー、およびモデレーターは削除済みの投稿を閲覧したり、削除取り消しの投票ができます」みたいな感じですかね。あるいはもっと短くして、詳しくはメタのFAQへという形にするか。

Comment: @unarist  ローカライズで対処していただけるとすると、仕様の変更への追随などは大変なので細かい事は省いた方がよいかも知れないですね。とは言っても、あまり短かい表現は思い付かないです。削っても「※権限を持つ一部のユーザーは削除後も投稿を閲覧出来ます」くらいにはなってしまいそうです。

Comment: 更に削って`一部のユーザーは削除後も投稿を観覧できます`にしたり、`高い権限を持つユーザーに観覧される可能性があります`くらいかな。